# What is better in terms of memory usage or compile time?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, methods

Which of these C++ methods is better in terms of memory usage? Is there any difference?

```
std::string MyClass::read ( std::size_t startRow, std::size_t startCol, std::size_t endRow, std::size_t endCol )
{
  std::size_t currentRow = startRow;
  std::size_t currentCol = startCol;
  while(currentRow < endLine ...)
    ......
  }
  return ...
}
```

or the same with:

```
std::string MyClass::read (BoxPtr boxPointer)
{
   std::size_t currentRow = boxPointer->getFirstRow;
   std::size_t currentCol = boxPointer->getFirstCol;

   while(currentRow < boxPointer->getEndRow ...)
   {
     ......
   }
}
```

Where the call for these is obviously:

```
std::string str = read(boxPointer);
std::string str = read(boxPointer->getFirstRow, boxPointer->getFirstCol ...)
```

Is there in general any difference in memory usage or in compile time?

Comment: Is memory usage an issue? I would recommend the later simply because it simplifies the function signature.

Comment: There is no (dynamic) memory usage, stay simple, just pass two arguments - hence the first is good

Comment: Also: If you have already a `BoxPtr` have a second inline function forwarding to the first

Comment: Is will depend if arguments go in registers or in the stack...

Comment: @DieterLücking: If `BoxPtr` has a constructor taking the same arguments in C++11 there already is `read({startRow, startCol, ...})`.

Comment: Having a `BoxPtr' is suspicious, anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: that assumes `MyClass::read(const Box&)` or `MyClass::read(Box)` or `MyClass::read(Box&&)` whereas OP uses `BoxPtr`

Comment: From a design perspective, it could make sense (depending on the full example) to make the read() function a member function of the Box class, since you are accessing internal data of it.

Comment: The compiler can probably optimise `read(boxPointer->getFirstRow, boxPointer->getFirstCol ...)` better than `read(boxPointer)`.

Comment: @fex: I would say `Box` is just a *Rectangle*, so it is used just a range. (so `MyClass::Read` makes more sense).

Comment: To me the variant with one parameter looks better and more consistent, also if boxPointer is not supposed to change in that function, I would give it as a const reference:
`std::string MyClass::read (BoxPtr const& boxPointer)` which might save some cycles when this function is called.

Comment: @Ashalynd: how do you think making it `const` might save cycles?  `const` is a compile-time enforced notion, and the compiler has to operate properly if `const_cast<>` removes constness or the object has `mutable` members.

Comment: @Jarod42 If that is the case, `MyClass` shouldn't have a dependency on `Box` (i.e. the first `read()` variant should be used). (But it's all just speculation anyway since we do not know the context of the code... ;))

Comment: Passing the object by const reference means there is no temporary copy of the argument that has to be created and destroyed, doesn't it?

Comment: @Ashalynd Correct. Using a reference saves the cycles (copying of the object), not the `const`.

Comment: @Ashalynd: a reference to a pointer can be expected to be implemented similarly to a pointer to a pointer... for inlined code it will normally be optimised away, but for out-of-line `read()` it implies an extra indirect read to get the pointer value before that pointer allows the row/col counters themselves to be accessed - that can only degrade performance.  Whether it's `const` or not doesn't matter performance wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there in general any difference in memory usage or in compile time?"

Jarod42's absolutely correct: "[It] will depend if arguments go in registers or in the stack..."

Elaborating on that...

Say your compiler/OS use an argument passing convention where the first N parameters are placed in registers, and further parameters on the stack (which will be slower even with caching).

If N is at least 1, but less than 4, then you can pass the pointer more cheaply than all the parameters (the compiler will hopefully manage to arrange for the caller to load the pointer directly in to the same register `read()` will want it in, but if not a register-to-register copy can be expected to be a 1-cycle operation).  It may use memory for the register copying machine code, but no stack memory or machine opcodes for pushing or popping.

If N is four or more (***very*** likely), then it makes no difference to stack memory usage which interface is used, though again the exact machine code may be more verbose for one than the other... your code assues a `boxPointer` already exists in the caller, so it's always cheap to pass that and takes none or minimal machine code to ensure it's in the expected register.  If all four paramters must be passed in specific registers, that could involve more caller-side machine code.  Countering that, the machine code inside `read()` to get to the four values via the pointer could be a few bytes larger on some CPUs.  Having a larger function is generally better than more caller-side code needed to call it, as there can be many more call sites.

If you really care about memory usage enough to be interested in the balance on your system, then compile and examine your generated code.

---

You can confidently expect there to be no significant difference to compile times with either interface.